# Ponteiro de struct dentro de uma struct

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, alocação

Não consigo atribuir valor a uma variável de um ponteiro de `struct` dentro de uma `struct`.

Minhas `structs`:

```
typedef struct notas{
    float geral;
    float especifica;
}Notas;

typedef struct data{
    int dia,mes,ano;
}Data;

typedef struct local{
    char ender[81];
    int sala;
}Local;

typedef struct candidatos{
    int inscr;
    char nome[81];

    Local *loc;
    Data nasc;
    Notas nota;
}Candidatos;
```

E o código que deveria atribuir valores:

```
void ler_candidatos(Candidatos *A, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Digite numero de inscriçao: ");
        scanf("%d",&A[i].inscr);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o nome: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]",A[i].nome);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o endereço: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]",A[i].loc->ender); //erro aqui.
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite a sala: ");
        scanf("%d",&A[i].loc->sala);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite sua data de nascimento: ");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&A[i].nasc.dia,&A[i].nasc.mes,&A[i].nasc.ano);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite sua nota geral: ");
        scanf("%f",&A[i].nota.geral);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite sua nota especifica: ");
        scanf("%f",&A[i].nota.especifica);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está sendo alocado o objeto que é recebido no parâmetro `A`? Sempre que você tem um tipo que um ponteiro para alguma coisa você vai ter que alocar espaço para essa alguma coisa, já que o que será guardado naquela variável ou membro de uma estrutura é apenas o ponteiro e não o dado. Em geral você terá que usar um [`malloc()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) para isto.

Comment: Olá user18400, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português :) separei seu código em dois para evitar a barra de rolagem, que atrapalha um pouco na leitura de código #FicaADica.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Mais ou menos é isto que precisa fazer:

```
A[i].loc = malloc(sizeof(Local));
scanf("%[^\n]",A[i].loc->ender); //agora o loc aponta para algum lugar preparado p/ receber o ender
printf("Digite a sala: ");
scanf("%d",&A[i].loc->sala);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MemberStruct.c).

Você precisa alocar a memória para o objeto apontado pelo ponteiro no elemento `loc`. Ali só é guardado o ponteiro para o dado e não o dado. Este dado precisa ser alocado na memória e seu endereço será guardado no ponteiro. A alocação ocorre com [`malloc()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Da maneira como estava você estava tentando acessar o `ender` e o `sala` de um local não definido, um ponto da memória que pode ser considerado aleatório.

Quando você for apagar um elemento de A terá que lembrar de liberar a memória com [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).

Não verifiquei se tem outros problemas, foquei no que foi perguntado.